# IntelliJ IDEA: SVN merge

Tags: svn, ide, merge, intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.3 installed and I have trunk and branch in SVN.
I use IDEA to merge from branch to trunk, and call command Subversion->Integrate Directory.
Source 1 is branch, Source 2 is trunk, unticked "Use ancestry", depth "infinity".
The problem is: it marks files even without changes as modified (and shows no differences in "Show Diff") after merge.
How would I solve that? I want these unmodified files not be available for commit.

Comment: why did u untick "use ancestry" and choose depth "inifinity" rather than "working copy"? iirc, the defaults have worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for response @vikingsteve! Of course I've tried with default settings but it lead me to the same results. AFAIK "use ancestry" takes URLs in consideration while merging, but URLs are definitely not same, so I stick to comparing only contents with unticking it. Is it possible that SVN marks unmodified files as changed because the branch was created by copying files from trunk to branch (not `svn copy`) and committing it to repo?